# XOR output is wrong in Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, xor

I am performing following operation

```js
let a = 596873718249029632;
a ^= 454825669;
console.log(a);
```

Output is  **454825669** but the output should have been **596873718703855301**. Where I am doing wrong? What I should do to get **596873718703855301** as output?

EDIT: I am using nodejs Bigint library , my node version is 8.12.0

```
var bigInt = require("big-integer");

let xor = bigInt(596873718249029632).xor(454825669);
console.log(xor)
```

Output is

```
{ [Number: 596873717794203900]
  value: [ 4203941, 7371779, 5968 ],
  sign: false,
  isSmall: false }
```

It is wrong. it should have been  **596873718703855301**.

Comment: Your first number is too large, you can use big-ints instead though: `596873718249029632n ^ 454825669n`

Comment: when I use above syntax in nodejs , it is throwing "SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token" error

Comment: BigInts are new, so if you're using Safari, IE or an outdated browser then you'll face issues: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt#Browser_compatibility

Answer (score 4):

From [MDN documentation about XOR](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_XOR):

> The operands are converted to 32-bit integers and expressed by a series of bits (zeroes and ones). Numbers with more than 32 bits get their most significant bits discarded.

Since the 32 least significant bits of `596873718249029632` are all 0, then the value of `a` is effectively `0 ^ 454825669`, which is `454825669`.

To get the intended value of `596873718703855301`, [BigInts](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt) can be used, which allow you to perform operations outside of the range of the `Number` primitive, so now your code would become:

```js
let a = 596873718249029632n;
a ^= 454825669n;

console.log(a.toString());
```

---

In response to your edit, when working with integers and `Number`, you need to ensure that your values do not exceed `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER` (equal to 2<sup>53</sup> - 1, beyond that point the double precision floating point numbers loose sufficient precision to represent integers). The following snippet worked for me:

```
var big_int = require("big-integer");
let xor = bigInt("596873718249029632").xor("454825669");
console.log(xor.toString());
```

Comment: Thanks you . it worked. I forgot toString() command

Comment: Glad I could help, if you found my answer useful [please consider accepting it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).